# Нерациональная организация кода

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7, веб-программирование

Пишу прогу для WP7, наблюдаю какой-то дикий уровень абстракции. Казалось бы нужен обычный парсер страницы в интернете, но для этого нужно создать вспомогательную функцию в которой уже будет обрабатываться полученный текст... (`this.textBlock1.Text = xdoc.FirstNode.ToString();`)

```
private void btn1_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    rectangle1.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(100,0, 0, 255));

    var url = "http://export.yandex.ru/weather-ng/forecasts/28698.xml";

    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    wc.DownloadStringCompleted += HttpsCompleted;
    wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url));

}

private void HttpsCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Error == null)
    {
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result, LoadOptions.None);
        this.textBlock1.Text = xdoc.FirstNode.ToString();
    }
    else 
    {
        this.textBlock1.Text = "ошибка";
    }
}
```

И это самый простой пример, который я смог найти в интернете. А если мне нужно будет данные полученные вторым запросом присвоить другому элементу, то придется дублировать этот вспомогательный метод, что за бред!?

Может быть, я не понимаю какой то скрытый замысел всего этого действа, почему нельзя сделать метод который и будет возвращать полученный код со страницы?

PS сильно не пинайте)

PPS вот это запись для меня вообще остается загадкой о__О (полный бред, но работает)

```
wc.DownloadStringCompleted += HttpsCompleted;
```

Comment: **wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url));** - качаем файл асинхронно

**wc.DownloadStringCompleted += HttpsCompleted;** - по завершению запускаем **HttpsCompleted**

Comment: Грубо говоря, на время скачивания приложение не блокируется.
Для мобильного приложения это вдвойне важно.

Comment: Можно ли из этого сделать в общих чертах так:<br>
private void btn1_click (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){<br>
    var p = foo(url); //в p данные с запрашиваемой страницы<br>
}<br>
мне кажется странным, что запрашиваемые данные в итоге приходят в метод HttpsCompleted....

Comment: вы просто не понимаете сути асинхронного выполнения кода

Answer (score 2):

wc.DownloadStringCompleted += HttpsCompleted - особого бреда тут нет. Это всего лишь пример перегрузки оператора +=, которая вполне уместна  в случае с делегатами в том числе. А что касается описанного выше кода, то написан он крайне ужасно, на уровне студента-первокурсника, так что ваш вопрос вполне уместен